# Passing a pointer to bufio.Scanner()

Tags: go, concurrency, memory-mapped-files

Lest I provide [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), my goal is to share a memory-mapped file between multiple goroutines [as recommended](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/363108/47835). Each goroutine needs to iterate over the file line by line so I had hoped to store the complete contents in memory first to speed things up.

The method I tried is passing a pointer to a `bufio.Scanner`, but that is not working. I thought it might be related to needing to set the seek position back to the beginning of the file but it is not even working the very first time and I can find no such parameter in the documentation. My attempt was to create this function then pass the result by reference to the function I intend to run in a goroutine (**for right now, I am *not* using goroutines** just to make sure this works outright, which it does not).

Here is a MWE:

```
// ... package declaration; imports; yada yada

func main() {
    // ... validate path to file stored in filePath variable
    filePath := "/path/to/file.txt"

    // get word list scanner to be shared between goroutines
    scanner := getScannerPtr(&filePath)

    // pass to function (no goroutine for now, I try to solve one problem at a time)
    myfunc(scanner)
}

func getScannerPtr(filePath *string) *bufio.Scanner {
    f, err := os.Open(*filePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, "Error opening file\n")
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    return scanner
}

func myfunc(scanner *bufio.Scanner) {
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := strings.TrimSpace(scanner.Text())
        // ... do something with line
    }
}
```

I'm not receiving any errors, it just is not iterating over the file when I call `Scan()` so it never makes it inside that block to do anything with each line of the file. Keep in mind I am not even using concurrency yet, that is just my eventual goal which I want to point out in case that impacts the method I need to take.

- Why is `Scan()` not working?
- Is this is a viable approach if I intend to call `go myfunc(scanner)` in the future?

Comment: Yes it's valid. Are you absolutely certain there's data in the file at `filePath`? Also note that `scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)` is unnecessary, as that is the default `SplitFunc` for `Scanner`.

Comment: Nevermind, just saw the issue & posted answer. The note on `SplitFunc` is still valid though.

Answer (score 5):

You're closing the file before you ever use the `Scanner`:

```
func getScannerPtr(filePath *string) *bufio.Scanner {
    f, err := os.Open(*filePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, "Error opening file\n")
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close() // <--- Here
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    return scanner // <-- File gets closed, then Scanner that tries to read it is returned for further use, which won't work
}
```

Because `Scanner` does not expose `Close`, you'll need to work around this; the quickest is probably to make a simple custom type with a couple of embedded fields:

```
type FileScanner struct {
    io.Closer
    *bufio.Scanner
}

func getScannerPtr(filePath *string) *FileScanner  {
    f, err := os.Open(*filePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, "Error opening file\n")
        panic(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    return &FileScanner{f, scanner}
}

func myfunc(scanner *FileScanner) {
    defer scanner.Close()
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := strings.TrimSpace(scanner.Text())
        // ... do something with line
    }
}
```

Comment: So this code actually worked before I tried passing scanner as a pointer, to include with the `defer f.Close()` statement. I was under the impression that by that time the file was already in memory? (Obviously I'm confused, just trying to learn Go)

Comment: No, the file is not in memory. `Scanner` reads the file into a buffer, but only a limited amount of bytes, and not until `Scan` is called.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. I'll give this a whirl then accept if it works out. Thank you!

Comment: Well now it is iterating over the file so that part of this is resolved! (But unfortunately it is not working like before, arg -- on to the next bug...). Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, though, wouldn't I not want to call close until all of the goroutines have finished? And thus I would not want it inside `myfunc()`, but rather inside `main()`? My intention is to call `go myfunc()` multiple times.

Comment: I moved it to after each call in `main()` and that solved it. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, if they're sharing a scanner, you want the `Close` outside the goroutines. Just make sure you use a `WaitGroup` so you don't close it until they're all done with it.

Comment: So I'm actually getting a panic runtime error about `slice bounds out of range` when I try to call `Scan()` concurrently. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48027337/868044) for more details and please let me know if I did not implement this as you had intended. I'm still learning.

Comment: This answer still has my upvote as helpful, but I've unmarked it as accepted because [the answer is not correct.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48027597/868044)