# panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range when concurrently running as goroutine

Tags: go, concurrency, runtime-error

I'm calling a function as a goroutine and using a WaitGroup to prevent closing a shared Scanner before they all finish. The `myfunc()` function iterates over a file. I wanted to memory-map this file and share it between all of the goroutines rather than have the I/O chokepoint of reading from disk each time. I was told that this approach would work [in an answer to another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48026498/868044) However, while this function worked fine standalone, it's not working concurrently. I am receiving the error:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
```

but the error is when I call the `Scan()` method (not on a slice) which is confusing.

Here is a MWE:

```
// ... package declaration; imports; yada yada

// the actual Sizes map is much more meaningful, this is just for the MWE
var Sizes = map[int]string {
    10: "Ten",
    20: "Twenty",
    30: "Thirty",
    40: "Forty",
}

type FileScanner struct {
    io.Closer
    *bufio.Scanner
}

func main() {
    // ... validate path to file stored in filePath variable
    filePath := "/path/to/file.txt"

    // get word list scanner to be shared between goroutines
    scanner := getScannerPtr(&filePath)

    // call myfunc() for each param passed
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan string)
    for _, param := range os.Args[1:] {
        wg.Add(1)
        go myfunc(&param, scanner, ch)
        wg.Done()
    }

    // print results received from channel
    for range os.Args[1:] {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)  // print data received from channel ch
    }

    // don't close scanner until all goroutines are finished
    wg.Wait()
    defer scanner.Close()
}

func getScannerPtr(filePath *string) *FileScanner {
    f, err := os.Open(*filePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, "Error opening file\n")
        panic(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    return &FileScanner{f, scanner}
}

func myfunc(param *string, scanner *FileScanner, ch chan<-string) {
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := strings.TrimSpace(scanner.Text())
        // ... do something with line (read only)
        // ... access shared Sizes map when doing it (read only)
        ch <- "some string result goes here"
    }
}
```

I originally thought the issue was concurrent access to the shared Sizes map, but moving it inside `myfunc()` (and inefficiently redeclaring/redefining it every time) still resulted in the same error, which has to do with calling `Scan()`. I'm attempting to follow the guidance I received [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48026498/868044)

Here's the full stack trace of the panic:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

goroutine 6 [running]:
bufio.(*Scanner).Scan(0xc42008a000, 0x80)
        /usr/local/go/src/bufio/scan.go:139 +0xb3e
main.crack(0xc42004c280, 0xc42000a080, 0xc42001c0c0)
        /Users/dan/go/src/crypto_ctf_challenge/main.go:113 +0x288
created by main.main
        /Users/dan/go/src/crypto_ctf_challenge/main.go:81 +0x1d8
exit status 2
```

Line 81 is:

```
go myfunc(&param, scanner, ch)
```

Line 113 is:

```
for scanner.Scan() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually after review of the `Scan` source, it doesn't appear to be thread-safe. You can get around this by having one routine read off of the scanner, and any number of other routines consume lines and process them:

```
func main() {
    // ... validate path to file stored in filePath variable
    filePath := "/path/to/file.txt"

    // get word list scanner to be shared between goroutines
    scanner := getScannerPtr(&filePath)
    defer scanner.Close()

    // call myfunc() for each param passed
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan string)
    lines := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            lines <- scanner.Text()
        }
        close(lines)
    }()
    for _, param := range os.Args[1:] {
        wg.Add(1)
        go myfunc(param, lines, ch)
        wg.Done()
    }

    // print results received from channel
    for range os.Args[1:] {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)  // print data received from channel ch
    }

    // don't close scanner until all goroutines are finished
    wg.Wait()
}

func myfunc(param string, lines chan []byte, ch chan<-string) {
    for line := range lines {
        line = strings.TrimSpace(line)
        // ... do something with line (read only)
        // ... access shared Sizes map when doing it (read only)
        ch <- "some string result goes here"
    }
}
```

Also note that there's no point in `defer`ing the last line in a function; the whole point of `defer` is to call it somewhere in the body of the function and know it will be called after the function returns. Since you're using a `WaitGroup` to prevent the function returning until you're done with your scanner, you can safely defer the close immediately.

Comment: This is indeed the proper way to use scan, but I'd suggest creating the go routines before starting to read, otherwise you may fill up the channel and create a deadlock since nothing is draining it. Also `wg.Done()` should not be in main.

Comment: Will there be any issues with `myfunc` taking a byte slice channel whereas the lines channel was declared to take strings?

Comment: @veran it won't deadlock because the scanner is in a separate goroutine. It will sit and wait until the consumers come up. @Dan, byte slices and strings are easily convertible but it does cause an alloc. I went with string because that's what `Scanner.Text()` returns.

Comment: @Adrian ok that makes sense. Thank you again for all your time and help.

Comment: @Adrian this works for the first goroutine, but all after the first do not appear to properly iterate over lines for some reason. Not sure why

Comment: It appears that every goroutine is now receiving the same param even though that loop has not changed. But instead of solving the same one multiple times it solves it the first time but then cannot find the word every time thereafter. The logic here must be wrong somehow.

Comment: @Verran could this be why I'm having the issues that I am? (see above)

Comment: They're getting the same parameter because you're passing a pointer to a loop variable. It changes every iteration, so all routines will end up using the last one. Unless you're modifying the parameter in the function, there's no reason to pass a pointer anyway, just pass the value.

Comment: @Adrian this *mostly* works but still has problems every iteration. I have been passing it the same four paramters over and over and consistently it does not find the word for the last two every time (and which two that is changes with every execution). There is still some logic error in this code where it does not iterate over every word in lines each time or something. Could the file be getting closed prematurely somehow? Or could this be the deadlock Verran referred to above? Is is somehow removing items from lines which could be the problem? Each goroutine needs access to *all* lines.

Comment: The deadlock mentioned does not occur with this code, and would manifest as a deadlock, not unexpected behavior. Each line is processed by a single goroutine, the same as your original implementation. If you want every line handled by every routine you'll need a different implementation.

Comment: Arg... looks like I'm back to square one. Thank you for your help, though!

Comment: But I do believe this was clear when I wanted to share the scanner by pointer: all goroutines need access to the full file contents.

Comment: If you share the scanner, each line will go to a goroutine. It only has one internal pointer. Needing to multiplex each line to multiple goroutines is a different problem altogether. It can be done in a similar fashion, with one channel per worker, sending each line from the scanner to all the channels. Just a little more complex.